# React-Native-Meteor update React-Native 0.33

Tags: meteor, reactjs, react-native

I'm running a Meteor server and a React-Native client (working in iOS mainly for now). Since I updated to React-native 0.33 the MeteorListView Component throws the following error:

[image: Screenshot Error]

My 'UserDos' follows the example of [InProgress-team/react-native-meteor](https://github.com/inProgress-team/react-native-meteor). When replacing the  MeteorListView with a regular ListView everything works fine. Is anyone experiences this issue or can pinpoint/direct me to solving the issue?

**Version**

"react": "^15.3.1",

"react-native": "^0.33.0",

"react-native-lock": "^0.4.0",

"react-native-meteor": "^1.0.0-rc15",

"react-native-scrollable-tab-view": "^0.6.0",

"react-redux": "^4.4.5",

"redux": "^3.6.0",

"redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed by reinstalling macOS and fresh install of React-native and dependances. Bit extreme solution but probably some complications with development version and upgrades; did the trick though!